# database query needed for the following qn

Tags: database

i have 3 database 
supplier(sid:integer,sname:string,Address:string)
parts:(pid:integer,pname:string,color:string)
catalog(sid:number,pid:number,cost:string)

qn: find names of suppliers who supply only green parts

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you attempted? Where are you having problems?  This site is for those STUCK because they've tried a few things.  This shows limited effort on solving the problem yourself.  Please review FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Did I answer your question below?  I would appreciate knowing if the query did what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you are storing your colors (i.e. HTML color defintion, name or what) but a query like this might do the trick:

```
select supplier.name
from supplier
where  supplier.sid in (
-- all the suppliers who supply green parts
select distinct(a.sid)
from catalog a 
inner join parts b on a.pid = b.pid     
where b.color = 'green')

and supplier.sid not in (       

-- all the supplier ids who supply parts that are not green
select distinct(a.sid)
from catalog a 
inner join parts b on a.pid = b.pid     
where b.color <> 'green')
```

This returns the supplier names that ONLY stock green parts.

Answer (score 0):

select supplier.sid, supplier.sname, supplier.Address from catalog where part.color = 'green' left join supplier on (catalog.sid = supplier.sid)
left join part on (catalog.pid = parts.pid);

Comment: Won't that return all the suppliers who supply green parts (plus other colors)?  The question says  the suppliers that supply only green parts.  I think you may need an inner query...

Comment: can you please tell me more simplified one